# Getting Kopete to work with Google voice chat on GNOME - FC14 - x86_64

Tags: fedora, google-talk, google-voice, kopete, google-video

Kopete works great with Google Talk, but I have not been able to use Google voice chat either on Google Chrome or Kopete.
Skype works great.
Please advise.